# understanding elements in a matrix

Tags: r, matrix, filter

I'm trying to understand more about matrices in R and I stumbled upon this query. Could someone explain to me why x[2:3, 2:2] returns 5 and 6?

Am I right to say that, 2:3, 2:2, simply refers to row 2, column 2 and row 3 column 2?

```
> x <- matrix(c(1:6), ncol = 2)
> x
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    4
[2,]    2    5
[3,]    3    6
> 
> 
> x[2:3, 2:2]
[1] 5 6
```

If that's the case, why is it that having a 3x3 matrix returns such a strange value?

```
> x <- matrix(c(1:9), ncol = 3)
> x
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    4    7
[2,]    2    5    8
[3,]    3    6    9
> x[1:2, 3:2, drop = F]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    7    4
[2,]    8    5
```

Comment: Because you are subsetting rows 2 and 3, of column 2.  As it is a single column output, it drops the dimensions `x[2:3, 2:2, drop = FALSE]`

Comment: What is strange in that.  You are subsetting by rows and columns.  You can check `x[1:2, 3]#
[1] 7 8
> x[1:2, 2]
#[1] 4 5`.  What do you expect as a solution?  If you are looking forward to extract the elements, use a matrix of row/column index i.e. `x[cbind(1:2, 3:2)]`

Comment: Think like a computer. It can only do one after the other. First: find rows 1 and 2, then: take the result and find columns 3 and 2.